# Using TransactionScope with SQLite causes database locked exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactionscope

I am trying to adapt a c# code that uses `TransactionScope` and works with Oracle to work also with SQLite. My code is structured in a way that every method called within the transaction scope that accesses the SQLite database creates its own `SQLiteConnection` object.

Now I have run into a problem when trying to open a second connection within the `TransactionScope` block. I am taking care to properly dispose of all the unused `SQLiteConnection` objects by either wrapping them in a using statement or calling `Dispose` in a finally block. No matter what I do the second call to `SQLiteConnection.Open` times out after a while with 
*database is locked* exception.

Example code:

```
using(var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    using(var connection1 = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection1.Open();
        ... // Do stuff with the open connection

    } // Closes the connection 

    using(var connection2 = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        // database locked exception
        connection2.Open();          
        ... 
    } 
}
```

All I have found out about the issue so far is in this article:http://elegantcode.com/2010/07/02/using-transactionscope-with-sqlite/ which says:

> The TransactionScope holds an exclusive writer lock, even when
>   disposing the first connection. Because the first connection cannot
>   fully close itself, opening the second connection results in a lock
>   error.

Unfortunately the article doesn't offer any workaround. I'd very much like to stick to using `TransactionScope` since having to pass `SQLiteConnection` and `SQLiteTransaction` objects to every method in my code would be a lot of rewrite effort not to mention the code would look much more messy. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try using "BeginTransaction" method of SQLiteConnection instead of Transaction Scope?

Comment: yes, this works but it's also quite inconvenient since all the methods accessing the database would need to share the same connection object.

Comment: I agree, but it seems that transaction scope don't work very well with SQLite

Comment: I was having similar issues; see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721283/transactionscope-and-sqlite-database-gets-locked#36631497).

Comment: After re-reading your question, I'm not sure there is a workaround. As I understand it, attempting to open a second connection promotes the transaction to an MSDTC transaction (and in so doing transfers the lock ownership to MSDTC), so the open will always fail.  I guess my question would be, why are you opening a second connection? The Oracle code was doing it that way, yes ... I'm asking *why* was the Oracle code structured thusly?