# Seeding SQLite with Entity Framework - Performance Problems

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert, query-performance

### Introduction

I am trying to seed a SQLite DB with Entity Framework but it's unacceptably slow.

I have an entity `MyEntity` with 5 columns which has a composite key consists of 3 columns.

### Initial approach

```
dbContext.MyEntity.AddOrUpdate(x => new{x.Key1,  x.Key2, x.Key3}, myEntities.ToArray());
```

This works incredibly slow. 1138 rows in 40 seconds.

### Another Try

Then using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182033/using-transactionscope-with-sqlite-causes-database-locked-exception), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721283/transactionscope-and-sqlite-database-gets-locked#36631497) and [this](https://www.djamseed.com/2015/08/31/improving-bulk-insert-performance-with-entity-framework/) I came up with this block:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{

    DatabaseContext dbContext;

    using (dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {

        dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < myEntities.Count; i++)
        {
            dbContext.MyEntity.AddOrUpdate(
                x => new
                {
                    x.Key1,
                    x.Key2,
                    x.Key3

                },
                myEntities.ElementAt(i));

            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                dbContext.Dispose();
                dbContext = new DatabaseContext();
                dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            }

        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        dbContext.Dispose();
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Sadly, I get:

> Message: Test method threw exception: 
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: database is locked
>   database is locked

### Trying with BulkExtensions library

I also tried [BulkExtensions library](https://github.com/tiagoln/BulkExtensions) like this: `dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(myEntities)`

resulted with following exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: database schema has changed near
>   "0": syntax error

I believe this happens because I haven't provided the information (there is no way to provide) of the composite key.

### The Question

How can I seed a SQLite DB in a reasonable time?